# What is the difference between go get and go install?

Tags: go

After playing with the `go` tool for a while, it looks like `go get`:

1. (optionally) downloads,
2. compiles,
3. and installs

a piece of software, while `go install` simply

1. compiles
2. and installs

it. In this case, why does the `go install` command exist, since `go get` supersedes it?

Comment: for future people: *"use of `go get` to build and install packages is deprecated. In a future release, the -d flag will always be enabled."* So, `go get` is only for download now.

Comment: Regarding the why question: https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`go install` is part of the workflow when working locally. Say you want to use a library, but for some reason a change is required. You would do:

- `go get -d library`, which only downloads it;
- make the change on the downloaded package;
- `go install library` to install the local version.

As far as I know `go get` has no flags to indicate it should *not* download, so it can't replace `go install` here.

The same workflow is used when you develop a new package from scratch.

EDIT: six years later, Go 1.16 has updated and clarified the usage of `go install` and `go get`: https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.16#modules

> `go install`, with or without a version suffix (as described above), is now the recommended way to **build and install packages** in module mode. `go get` should be used with the `-d` flag to **adjust the current module's dependencies without building packages**, and use of `go get` to build and install packages is deprecated. In a future release, the `-d` flag will always be enabled.

Comment: Nice, I think I understand now thanks to your first example. However, in your second one (developing a new package from scratch) I could use `go get ./path/to/local_package` too, and it would behave the same as if I used `go install ./path/to/local_package`, right? Since there is no download process in this case.

Comment: `go install` makes your goal more explicit, but I suppose both would achieve the same thing. I tested with a few packages, including ones declared as `main` and they seemed equivalent. The docs are very lacking on this command.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/master/README.md#installation) it says, you need gcc for `go get` but not for `go install`. How does that relate to this description?

Comment: I disagree with this answer. You can use `go get` instead of `go install` in your third bullet point too, since `go get` will not re-download the library (unless you add `-u`). You can also use `go get` when writing a library from scratch. `go install` seems completely redundant.

Answer (score 61):

`go get` does two main things in this order:

- downloads and saves in `$GOPATH/src/<import-path>` the packages (source code) named in the import paths, along with their dependencies, then
- executes a `go install`

The `-d` flag (`go get -d`) instructs `go get` to stop after downloading the packages; that is, it instructs `go get` not to do `go install`

---

***the difference:***

`go get` // verify if packages need to be downloaded, download if needed then compile

`go install` // skip the part with packages download, just compile  (this will throw an error if any packages are missing)

---

***about `GOPATH` environment variable***

The `GOPATH` environment variable is used by the Go tools. It must be set in order to be able to `get`, `build` and `install` packages, and it specifies the location of your workspace. It is likely the only environment variable you'll need to set when developing Go code.

Again, the `GOPATH` should not point to the Go installation, but rather to your workspace.

For example, on Windows, if you decide that your workspace is at `c:\gowork\`, you will need to set `GOPATH` value as `c:\gowork`

[image]

Your source code should be at `c:\gowork\src\<some project folder>\` and after you run `go get` at command prompt from within `c:\gowork\src\<some project folder>\` you will see the `c:\gowork\bin\` and `c:\gowork\pkg\` being created.

Comment: `go install` does download the package in module-aware set-up.

Answer (score 25):

Note that [go 1.16 (Q1 2021)](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command) will make that difference clearer, implemented with [CL 266360](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/266360/) as part of [issue 40276](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40276):

> `go install` now accepts arguments with version suffixes (for example, `go install example.com/cmd@v1.0.0`).
> This causes `go install` to **build and install packages in module-aware mode**, **ignoring the `go.mod` file** in the current directory or any parent directory, if there is one.
> This is **useful for installing executables without affecting the dependencies of the main module**.
>
> `go install`, with or without a version suffix (as described above), is now the recommended way to build and install packages in module mode.
>
> **`go get`** should be used with the `-d` flag to adjust the current module's dependencies without building packages, and **use of `go get` to build and install packages is deprecated**.
> In a **future release, the `-d` flag will always be enabled**.

---

In June 2022 (Go 1.18 right before 1.19), [Chris Siebenmann](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/) details "[a limitation on what '`go install`' can install](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/programming/GoInstallLimitation)".

It involves a module with a [`replace` directive](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Edit_go_mod_from_tools_or_scripts):

> If you clone the [repository](https://github.com/monsterxx03/gospy) and run '`go install`' inside it, everything works and you wind up with a `gospy` binary in your `$HOME/go/bin`.
>
> However, as we see here '`go install ...@latest`' works differently enough that the replace directive causes this error.

That triggers the error message:

```
go: github.com/monsterxx03/gospy@latest (in github.com/monsterxx03/gospy@v0.5.0):
    The go.mod file for the module providing named packages contains one or
    more replace directives. It must not contain directives that would cause
    it to be interpreted differently than if it were the main module.
```

The [help for 'go install'](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) explicitly says about this mode:

> No module is considered the "`main`" module.
>
> If the module containing packages named on the command line has a `go.mod` file, it must *not* contain directives (`replace` and `exclude`) that would cause it to be interpreted differently than if it were the main module.
> The module must not require a higher version of itself.

See:

- [issue 44840](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44840): `cmd/go`: `go install cmd@version` errors out when module with `main` package has `replace` directive
- [issue 40276](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40276): `cmd/go`: `go install` should install executables in module mode *outside* a module
- [issue 45099](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45099): `x/tools/gopls`: cannot install `gopls` v0.6.8 (illustrates the issue)

Recommendation:

> switch to using **[Go workspaces](https://go.dev/ref/mod#workspaces)** for local development and drop the `go.mod` `replace` directives entirely.

As mentioned in "[Get familiar with workspaces](https://go.dev/blog/get-familiar-with-workspaces)" by [Beth Brown](https://go-review.googlesource.com/q/owner:ecbrown%2540google.com):

> Previously, to add a feature to one module and use it in another module, you needed to either publish the changes to the first module, or [edit the `go.mod` file](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/call-module-code) of the dependent module with a `replace` directive for your local, unpublished module changes.
>
> In order to publish without errors, you had to *remove* the `replace` directive from the dependent module’s `go.mod` file after you published the local changes to the first module.
>
> With Go workspaces, you control all your dependencies using a **go.work** file in the root of your workspace directory.
> The `go.work` file has `use` and `replace` directives that **override the individual `go.mod` files**, so there is no need to edit each `go.mod` file individually.

Comment: maybe I just don't know the reasoning behind this... but I don't see why you would want to disable a single build/install command. this is different from any other package manager I've seen

Comment: @TrevorJex re-reading https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40276, there still is a single build/install command: `go install`. And it does so, installing  packages
at specific versions, regardless of the current module context. That is an improvment compared to the old `go get`.

Answer (score 5):

from [doc](https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation):

> Starting in Go **1.17, installing executables with go get is deprecated**. go install may be used instead.
>
> In Go 1.18, go get will no longer build packages; it will only be used to add, update, or remove dependencies in go.mod. Specifically, go get will always act as if the -d flag were enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this -
https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation

Referencing -

```
Starting in Go 1.17, installing executables with go get is deprecated. go install may be used instead.

In Go 1.18, go get will no longer build packages; it will only be used to add, update, or remove dependencies in go.mod. Specifically, go get will always act as if the -d flag were enabled.
```