# How to install the go bundle tool

Tags: go, go-bundle

I am trying to figure out how to install this:

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle

anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
go get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle"
```

or

```
go install "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle"
```

Comment: does this install the tool as a global command line tool by default, or do I need to install it in a place where gopath is "global"?

Comment: When I run `go install x` in $HOME, I get  `can't load package: package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle (from $GOROOT)
        /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/types-depot/test/builds/golang/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle (from $GOPATH)
        /home/oleg/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle
`

Comment: So yeah, I just have to run `go get` and that should be sufficient for global command line tool.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878737/what-is-the-difference-between-go-get-and-go-install. This will help you to know the cause.

Comment: thanks that is good, but I am still confused about when it creates a command program available in $PATH vs when it doesn't.