# What does it mean the code in my directory "expects" a particular import?

Tags: go

A Go language tutorial uses the "quote" package to get familiar quotes. When I give the command "go get -v rsc.io/quote", I get the message

code in directory.../github/hello/src/rsc.io/quote/v3 expects import "rsc.io/quote"

So I went there and looked at the code. It has an import statement:

```
import "rsc.io/quote/v3"
```

So I thought maybe I had the wrong version of quote. Accordingly, I tried "go get -v rsc.io/quite/v3" THis produces the message:

code in directory .../rsc.io/quote/v3 expects import "rsc.io/quote."

This seems circular: asking without a version number produces a requirement for a versioned package, but trying to get a versioned package produces a requirement without a version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
go get -v rsc.io/quote

get "rsc.io/quote": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"rsc.io/quote", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/rsc/quote"} at //rsc.io/quote?go-get=1
rsc.io/quote (download)
get "rsc.io/sampler": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"rsc.io/sampler", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/rsc/sampler"} at //rsc.io/sampler?go-get=1
rsc.io/sampler (download)
github/gospace/src/rsc.io/quote/quote.go:8:8: code in directory /Users/james/github/gospace/src/rsc.io/quote/v3 expects import "rsc.io/quote"
```

```
cat $GOPATH/src/rsc.io/quote/v3/go.mod
module rsc.io/quote/v3

require rsc.io/sampler v1.3.0
```

```
  ~> cat $GOPATH/src/rsc.io/quote/v3/go.sum
golang.org/x/text v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c h1:qgOY6WgZOaTkIIMiVjBQcw93ERBE4m30iBm00nkL0i8=
golang.org/x/text v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/go.mod h1:NqM8EUOU14njkJ3fqMW+pc6Ldnwhi/IjpwHt7yyuwOQ=
rsc.io/sampler v1.99.99 h1:7i08f/p5TBU5joCPW3GjWG1ZFCmr28ybGqlXtelhEK8=
rsc.io/sampler v1.99.99/go.mod h1:T1hPZKmBbMNahiBKFy5HrXp6adAjACjK9JXDnKaTXpA=
```

More about `go get` vs `go install`. [What is the difference between go get and go install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878737/what-is-the-difference-between-go-get-and-go-install)

Can you please check your GO env path settings:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/github/<your_workspace_name>                                                   
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Here is a good source for setting up workspace:

https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html

Comment: I get get "rsc.io/quote": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"rsc.io/quote", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/rsc/quote"} at //rsc.io/quote?go-get=1
package rsc.io/quote: cannot download, /home/anna_user2/go is a GOROOT, not a GOPATH. For more details see: 'go help gopath' Perhaps there is something wrong with how go is confugred. The output of by go env command says GOROOT is /usr/loca/go and GOPATH is /home/myusername/go

Comment: I set GOPATH as you suggested. When I ran "go get rsc.io/quote", I get ../github/hello/src/rsc.io/quote/quote.go:8:8: code in directory /home/anna_user2/github/hello/src/rsc.io/quote/v3 expects import "rsc.io/quote" I do not understand what it means when it says my code "expects" an import. Does that mean that the import failed? When I run "go run hello.go", I get the same message.

Comment: The link you gave for setting up a workspace asks me to create three additional directories. I am willing to do that if necessary, but since I don't know what is going on when there is only one directory, will it just add to the confusion to create three more? I see that it asks me also to create a directory with a path ending in the name "user" In general I do not understand the document on setting up a workspace. I do understand Linux, directories, environment variables, etc., but I don't know how Go configuration uses them

Comment: I do not understand why "github" appears in the path. What does this have to do with github? I use github for my code in other languages but I have not done anything about go in my github repository

Comment: The document on setting up a workspace uses the term "command executable." What is a "command executable?" A script, an executable binary, a go source file?

Comment: command executable is the executable code after you run `go install`

Comment: I looked in the folder where command executables go and see that they are "executables", i.e. binaries. When I run my go code with the command "go run hello.go" I am not saying "go install", so what is the difference between "go install" and "go run" if they both make executable binaries.

Answer (score 8):

If you continue the tutorial to the end you will see that the addition of a go module, and the subsequent initialisation, will resolve your issue. The .mod file will pull in the required dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

As @MartinBennett mentioned, it's already mentioned in the tutorial but may be not so clear.

Once you add `import "rsc.io/quote"` in your `hello.go` file, you will need to run these commands in your terminal:

1-

```
go mod init hello
```

2-

```
go run hello.go
```