# GoLang running "bundle": exec: "bundle": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go

Trying to run the bundle command with `go:generate bundle -o=h2_bundle.go -prefix=http2 -tags=!nethttpomithttp2 github.com/zMrKrabz/fhttp/http2`, but I am getting `running "bundle": exec: "bundle": executable file not found in $PATH`.

Every other go command works fine, and I have done `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle` but this does not fix anything.

Have tried to run `go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle`, but I get `cannot find package "." in: .../vendor/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle`, but *outside* of my Go project folder:

```
C:\Users\vonc>go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.1.2
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210510120138-977fb7262007

C:\Users\vonc>where bundle
C:\Users\vonc\go\bin\bundle.exe
```

That way, I am sure I don't mess with a go.mod project, although, since [Go 1.16, `go install` should work that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64800215/6309).