# Not able to watch go files after installing Compile Daemon

Tags: go, github, path, oh-my-zsh, gopath

Installed using, `go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon` and `go install github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon`

When I try to run it using -> `CompileDaemon --compile="./folderName"`

It gives -> `zsh: command not found: CompileDaemon`

Note:

- I'm using oh-my-zsh.
- My `GOPATH` and `GOBIN` are not default one's, I set it to `goWorkspace`

Answer (score 2):

First, don't forget that the [use of `go get` to build and install packages is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64800215/6309) (In earlier versions of Go, '`go get`' was used to build and install packages. Now, '`go get`' is dedicated to adjusting dependencies in `go.mod`.)

All you need should be [`go install`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies):

```
go install github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon@latest
```

That should generate a `CompileDaemon` executable in your directory named by the `GOBIN` environment variable.

But you need `$GOBIN` itself in your `$PATH` (from your `~/.zshrc` for instance):

```
export PATH="$PATH:$GOBIN"
```

Comment: I totally agree with you that go install will create ComileDaemon exectuable in GOBIN variable path. But when i try to execute it within present working directory it says, zsh command not found

Comment: @PrafulNalatwad Check first if the executable was indeed created in that `GOBIN` folder (and check that your `$PATH` does include said `GOBIN` folder). Check also the case (uper/lower) of the created binary.

Comment: Thanks for the above Hint, finally found the heck.. i was missing to include GOBIN to $PATH varibale in .zshrc file.

Comment: @PrafulNalatwad Well done. I have edited my answer to make that step more visible.

Answer (score 1):

Install Compile Daemon using
"go install github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon@latest"

Important:
Ensure that the Compile Daemon executable path(i.e: GOBIN) is included in $PATH.

You can include it by editing your ".bashrc" or ".zshrc" file.
or by "export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN"